# to know what size does the column stack bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've 2 column of `col-md-8` and and `col-md-4`, I resize the windows until an extend, the `col-md-4` stacked at the bottom, I want to do something at that size..

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you want to do, and a better understanding of the new col-*-* code is required. Look at the code below -

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="well col-xs-4 col-sm-5 col-md-6 col-lg-7">A</div>
    <div class="well col-xs-8 col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-5">B</div>   
</div>
```

At the 4 different sizes (xs, sm, md and lg) the column sizes will change for both div A and B.

- xs (extra small) will be a 4/8 split
- sm (small) will be a 5/7 split
- md (medium) will be a 6/6 split
- lg (large) will be a 7/5 split

This makes it really easy to display different layouts as the width of the screen changes.

(I've added the extra "well" class to make it easier for you to see the layout changes as they happen....)

Answer (score 0):

For the medium grid (col-md-) that point will add 992px (see also the table at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options). To do some css at this point use media queries (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Todo some javascript at this point will be more complicated. With `$(window).resize()` you could find the current size of your screen (`$(window),width`) but to trigger an action you need be exactly on the point or get your action trigger every resize on your screen below your point.
You could try to set a boolean like:

```
var action == false
$(window).resize(function()
    { 
         if(!action && $(window).resize()<992){ yourcation(); action=true; } 
         elseif(action && $(window).resize()>=992) {action=false; }
    });
```

You could also use Enquire.js (https://github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js/) to respond to CSS media queries with javascript. See also http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/responsive-banner-ads-2/ for some examples.